# Does anyone here use the make-cdf & stats.pl program?

Tags: c, perl, statistics, graph, plot

I came across this page: [Plotting Tools](http://moo.cmcl.cs.cmu.edu/wiki/index.php/Tools#make-cdf)

where I found a set of tools with the name stats.pl and make-cdf. I can write my own but don't want to spend too much time when someone else has already done that. Does anyone have these tools or at least point me to a similar set of tools somewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know who Dave, Binju, Vijay and Dan are and I did not see a way of figuring out what `stats.pl` and `make-cdf` contain.

There are a number of excellent [statistics related modules on CPAN](http://www.google.com/search?q=statistics+site%3Asearch.cpan.org) including [Statistics::Descriptive](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Statistics::Descriptive), [Statistics::KernelEstimation](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Statistics::KernelEstimation) and [Math::GSL::CDF](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Math::GSL::CDF) to name but a few that might be relevant given the names of the scripts you mention.

However, if you want to do serious statistics, I would recommend you consider using [R](http://www.r-project.org/) which you can control using [Statistics::R](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Statistics::R). AFAIK, the [R tag on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) is pretty active.

Comment: @Sinan, thanks for providing the info. This R looks interesting.

Comment: The modules look simply awesome. Thank You very much for the pointers.